# React stop propagation on native bindings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm busy wrestling with React and it's synthetic event system and the inability to block native events using the synthetic e.stopPropagation() method.

The scenario is that I have some dropdowns that toggle when they are clicked, that's working fine, no problems there. The issue I'm having is that I'd like to extend out this functionality so that when I click anywhere else on the screen any active dropdown should be disabled.

Naturally we are going to need some sort of global event handler to take care of this. I tried to simply create the global event binding during the component lifecycle and prevent any clicks on the children from bubbling up it looked something like this:

### Failed attempt to block propagation during click

```
class parent extends component {
  ...
  
  componentWillMount () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.someAction)
  }
 
  render () {
    return ...
  }
}

class child extends component {
  ...
  
  _handleClick (e) {
    e.stopPropagation() // Doesn't work
    
    // Do something
  }
}
```

From what I gather synthetic events can't override native events since react is bound at the document level and events that bubble will always fire last.

### Option 2 Get the Node using ReactDOM(Yuck)

The second option I found was to use ReactDOM to get the node and check the target of the click, if it matches the component then we simply don't trigger a reset on any active states.

Having to import ReactDOM to grab a node seems really cumbersome and excessive and I feel there is a cleaner solution out there.

### Options 3 Create a click handler at the root component

We could create a handler at the root component that handles global clicks, but now we've lost encapsulation since the we've moved logic for handling clicks associated with this small component all the way to the very top level again I don't like this solution.

It seems impossible to me that such a simple and straight forward task is so difficult to achieve using react. I'm not overly use to it so please can someone else point me down the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

So the best solution I've seen to solve this problem is to find the target of the clicked element and then recursively call the the targets parent and check if it matches the element you are interested in capturing.

If the parent node eventually reaches the document without matching on your element then you can safely conclude that the click was initiated from outside of your element.

https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside

This was the source code I found that solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try preventDefault() method

```
onReset(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is too vague, please be more specific in explaining how the code answers the question. Read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: I solved this a while back. I'll post an answer to my question below.